# Change line ending after cloning a git repository

Tags: windows, git, gitlab-ci-runner, conan

I am cloning a repository on one Windows and one GNU/Linux machine used as gitlab-runners. When the runner's job starts, the code has already been checked out.

I need those files to have the same line endings on both platforms. This is a [conan](http://conan.io/) requirement: some files will be uploaded and their checksums must match, hence they must use the same end of line characters conventions. So let's use LF everywhere.

My problem is that I have no control on how the cloning is done. There are some gitlab-ci variables I can set that control how the clone is done, like GIT_SUBMODULE_STRATEGY, etc., but none control line endings. So once the clone is done, I need to find a clean way of changing the end-of-line of the whole repository + submodules.

The obvious answer is to use `git config --global core.crlf false` but there are a few problems:

1. the line ending constraint exists only when building conan packages, so I'd prefer to not have this global in case the runner builds something else
2. it won't work if it's called from the runner job (by that time the code has already been checked out)

Because of `1` I tried something around `git config core.crlf false` (without `--global`), but problem `2` remains. There's also problem `3`:

3. it won't work with submodules

What I have tried to fix problem `2`:

- `git reset --hard` after changing `autocrlf` doesn't change the line endings.
- `git checkout .` after changing `autocrlf` changes them, but not always (worked on the main repo, didn't work inside a submodule)

So I'm looking for a way to get LF line endings from an already cloned repository, and that would work with submodules.

Comment: It seems the proposal in https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues/2997 is getting some support, I'd suggest to comment there, conan might eventually provide some line-ending agnostic hashing.

Comment: It's [not really getting support](https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues/2997#issuecomment-395035541). Which I understand, as there's little conan can do here IMHO. Changing the hash algorithm would break all packages around, is outside of their scope, and they would probably have a hard time not corrupting binary files. Git already has answers to that, it's better to not reinvent the wheel.